# Multiplying INT and TIME

Tags: php

I have to do some calculations which include variables of type INT and TIME. Something like this:

```
$A = 555;
$B = 0.555;
$C = '08:00:00';
$D = '06:45:56';

$E = $A * exp(-$B * ($C - $D) * 24);
echo "RESULT: " . $E;
```

How should I refactor the TIME type variables in order to make it work?

**SOLVED:**

@mlewis54 Gave the right answer but just in case anyone else is facing the same problem - notice you have to consider that **strtotime()** converts time into seconds so you will need to later convert these seconds into whatever you need (minutes/hours/days).

So instead of multiplying by 24 I had to divide by 3600 in my case in order to make it work.

```
$E = $A * exp(-$B * (($C - $D) / 3600));
```

Comment: What's the desired result? or to be more clear.. what do you want to calculate there?

Comment: These are just dummy variables but if I follow the approach below (convert $C and $D to ints which I tried before posting the question) the final result $E is 0 because for some reason the expression exp(...) is 0 and it shouldn't be. It is happening because of exp() but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert the $C and $D to ints and then do the math. Something like:

```
$CTIME=strtotime($C);
$DTIME=strtotime($D);
```